# Position absolute keeps pushing objects outside of the frame

Tags: html, css

Sorry, beginner in programming. but I am having an issue with some code.

I am trying to add a white background in the back of the text I, but there's a lot of empty white space in it. This: [example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdYTc.png)

What i am trying to make is this: [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njjEF.png)

So, my approach for this is putting the paragraph in a div, and giving it the following code:

```
.i_box{
    background-color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #1a1e23;
    padding-top: 0.2px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

and the tittle to have its background white, position absolute and margin big enough that it will go under the text, giving it the feeling like its same pannel.
But the tittle goes automatically on top of the page.

Why's this happening?

Here's an example of the code for the block:

```
<h2>The problem</h2>
<div class="i_box">
<p>test test test </p>
</div>
```

any suggestion please?
can't seem to figure this out

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not entirely sure what you want but I created something similar to what you asked for in image 2.
Here is a snippet:

```css
.i_box{
    background-color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #1a1e23;
    padding-top: 0.2px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    size: relative;
    
}
.title-thing{
   display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
}
.title-thing-parent{
  text-align: center;
  /* 
  to center .title-thing, added display: inline-block to .title-thing so it can work.
  */
}
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div class = "title-thing-parent"> 
<div class = "title-thing">
<h2 >The problem</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="i_box">
<p>test test test </p>
</div>

</body>
```

Added the display: inline-block to the title and surrounded it in another div so it can be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most simple way is to make your h2 have `display: inline-block` Look what I did here in an example:

```css
.i_box{
    background-color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #1a1e23;
    padding-top: 0.2px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}

h2 {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>The problem</h2>
<div class="i_box">
<p>test test test </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the coding for something similar to what you asked for.

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.i_box {
  background-color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #1a1e23;
  padding-top: 0.2px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  size: relative;
  /* margin-top: 30px; */
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>The problem</h2>
</div>
<div class="i_box">
  <p>test test test </p>
</div>
```